# How to re-enable an extension's update site

Tags: joomla-3.x, development, update

I have an extension shipped as a package, which combines a module, a plugin and a component.

I have the usual updateserver tag in my manifest:

```
<updateservers>
    <server type="extension" priority="1" name="myext">http://www.fasterjoomla.com/myext.xml</server>
</updateservers>
```

and a corrensponding file hosted on the server. A tag in this file was not properly set up, but it worked up until a few versions ago; then boom! Stopped working. (the package was set as admin instead of site).  So I fixed it, and it started working again.

Here comes the problem: the update site was disabled in most of my test sites due to the error.  And while Joomla 2.5 has a nice "Clean cache" button in the extension update page:

```
/administrator/index.php?option=com_installer&view=update
```

which invoked the

```
administrator/components/com_installer/controllers/update.php:purge()
```

function, which in turn invoked the `enableSites()` in the update model.

Alas I cannot find such button in Joomla 3.  And I tried debugging, but I can't see how this function would be invoked.

Help! Three thousands users are stuck with an old version, and they don't know it!

Update: I filed a bug:
http://joomlacode.org/gf/project/joomla/tracker/?action=TrackerItemEdit&tracker_item_id=34043&start=0

Comment: On a side note have you ever been to fast joomla dot com…

Comment: wow they literally sell fog! and the ttfb is 2.5s!!! they win, no questions asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comment on the issue on joomlacode from Brian:

"This has been resolved already and will be in the 3.4 release."

3.4 should be released shortly. All the discussion took place here: 
https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/pull/3775

Answer (score 1):

Go to the `Options` for the Joomla 3 `Installation Manager` and set the "Updates Caching (in hours)" value to 0 (zero).

[image: Joomla 3 Installer Manger Options]

According to the `JUpdater` doc's on the `findUpdates($eid = 0, $cacheTimeout = 0)` if it's set to zero it will force reload the update information.

```
/**
 * Finds an update for an extension
 *
 * @param   integer  $eid           Extension Identifier; if zero use all sites
 * @param   integer  $cacheTimeout  How many seconds to cache update information; if zero, force reload the update information
 *
 * @return  boolean True if there are updates
 *
 * @since   11.1
 */
public function findUpdates($eid = 0, $cacheTimeout = 0)
```

Comment: Will this also affect client who have downloaded the extension for their own site? Or will they have to perform thisaction too?

Comment: I may be misunderstanding your question, but this only affects the Joomla instance you do it on, it can't possibly affect other websites.

Comment: `Help! Three thousands users are stuck with an old version, and they don't know it!` I believe the this will still be an issie for all those people :/

Comment: Yup, that's why newsletters, twitter, facebook etc exist and for the four that aren't on those g+ :D

Comment: @cppl alas this is not working. findUpdates triggers purge, which resets the timestamp but does not re-enable the disable sites.

Comment: @lodder of course this won't affect users if I do it on my machine, and the component has a live feed in the latest versions; additionally, I will let the registered users on my site know with a mailing. This question was opened to understand how enableSites() is called in Joomla 3, but apparently it is not!